# Variável PHP em um value HTML

Tags: php, html

Como coloco a variável php no value seguinte:

```
<?php
    while($ver=mysql_fetch_row($busca)){ 
        $id1 = $ver[0];
?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" value="$id1"></td>
            <td><?php echo "$ver[0]"; ?></td>
    # code ...
```

Do modo que fiz `value="$id1"` não funcionou.
Apenas um dos "radios" deve ser selecionado,pra isso os values devem ser diferentes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a tag php `<?php echo $id1; ?>` ou `<?=$id1?>` (caso o php short tags esteja habilitado)

ex:

```
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $id1; ?>">
```

Comment: short tags facilita a vida !

Comment: Se a versão do PHP for `5.4 >=` não é necessário habilitar shortags. É nativo

Comment: Certo, mas não resolveu meu problema, tenho uma tabela com valores do banco de dados contidos num array, que são mostrados a partir do laço de repetição, e quero fazer com que selecione apenas uma das opções, pra isso os values devem ser diferentes:

Comment: @Eduardo, pois é, esse tipo de esclarecimento tem que estar ***dentro*** da sua pergunta.

Comment: @EduardoBalestrin esse tipo de informação já foge ao escopo da sua pergunta. Deve ser feita nova pergunta sobre isso, informando principalmente a sua estrutura sql para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Ok ok, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

No primeiro `<td>` você não pôs as *tags* do *PHP*.
No seguindo `<td>` você o fez mas esta usando um vetor e o interpretador de string tenta capturar apenas a `var` de tal forma que entendo o índex `[0]` como string e não índex.

#### Resolvendo

```
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $id1; ?>"> // var direto
ou
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $var[0]; ?>"> // var direto
ou
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo "{$var[0]}"; ?>"> // {} para indicar inicio e fim de var, inclui o index [0]
```